# Given a binary tree, traverse the left sub tree

Tags: binary-tree

It gives the correct output if we are to find nodes in the left sub tree and even on the root node but if we take any nodes on the right say root->right i.e., node 70 it gives a wrong output of 20 30 40 50 60. I know where I am making the mistake how should i modify the code such that for an input of 70 only it's left sub tree i.e., node 60 is printed.

```
void In(struct node *root1,struct node*root2) 
{
  if (root1 != NULL)
  {
    In(root1->left,root2);
     if(root1->key==root2->key)
       exit(0);
     else
       printf("%d ", root1->key);
    In(root1->right,root2);
   }
}
int main()
{
  /* Let us create following BST
          50
       /     \
      30      70
     /  \    /  \
   20   40  60   80 */
  struct node *root = NULL;
  root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);

  // print inoder traversal of the BST
   inorder(root);
   printf("\n");
   In(root,root->right);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to word your question better. Explain what the 2 arguments to `In()` are.

Comment: @KacyRaye The code gives incorrect output on an input of node 70 in the second argument of In function in main i.e, if were to find the left sub tree of node 70

Comment: So you're printing out the left subtrees of both arguments?

Comment: nope, first argument is the root node, second argument is the node whose lst we want. I am traversing the tree such that if the present node matches with the node whose lst we are req to find it simply exits and prints no more. Take a value say 50 u will understand the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Just do an in-order traversal on the left child.

```
void In( struct node *root1, struct node *root2 ) 
{
    if ( root1 != NULL && root2 != NULL )
    {
        if ( root1 -> key == root2 -> key)
            exit(0);

        inorder( root2 -> left );  
    }
}
```